# Pinescript reverse split read out in tradingview

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Short Question:

TradingView shows (when enabled) the reverse splits on the chart (in yellow, where the earnings and news are shown), including its ratio. Is it possible to use Pinescript to read the reverse split ratio?

I really don't know. If it is possible, I'm going to refine my question, but if not, I see no need.

**edit:** Thanks to vgladkov there is the call security.split().
However, it shows the split occuring on a specific day. The rest of the timeseries data are empty. Suppose I have obtained the split-series "split". Days with no split are valued na. So i figured I could first extract the split indices like this

```
split_index=na(split) ? split : bar_index
```

This gives the time-series with na everywhere except at the days where a split occurs it gives the bar-index. But I would rather like to safe the few indices inside a separate (non-series) array and use this array (within a loop) to compare if the na-days are left or right of a specific index. Is that possible?

I'm pretty new to pinescript, but the idea of what I intent to do is outlined here. It obviously doesn't work yet. As I understand the code you write is (implicitly) looped over every bar, right? So I'm still trying to figure out how to create full lists of arrays within each "loop".

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Short Ratio", shorttitle="SR", format=format.percent, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

ticker = syminfo.tickerid
ticker_symbol = syminfo.ticker
short_symbol = "FINRA:" + ticker_symbol + "_SHORT_VOLUME"
short_volume = request.security(short_symbol, timeframe.period, close)
split_n = request.splits(ticker, splits.numerator, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
split_d = request.splits(ticker, splits.denominator, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
split = split_n / split_d

split_yn=array.new_int(0,0)
if na(split)
    array.push(split_yn,0)
else
    array.push(split_yn,1)

split_f=input.float(1)
index_split=array.indexof(split_yn,1)
while index_split != -1
    split_f := bar_index < index_split ? split_f * split[index_split] : split_f
    split_yn[index_split] = 0
    index_split := array.indexof(split_yn,1)

short_ratio = short_volume / volume * 100 * split_f


plot( short_ratio , linewidth=1, color=color.black, style=plot.style_columns)
```

Comment: yes, you can get split coeff by security.split() function

Comment: The value of all splits cannot be known on the first bar, this contradicts the concept of Pine’s execution. In this way, you will kind of look into the “future”; this can theoretically work on historical data, because all these splits have already happened, but Pine is performed from left to right, simulating what will happen in reality, that is, today you cannot know what the split will be in a month, so analyzing the historical “today” also makes no sense based on what will happen in the future relative to the historical “today”

What is your goal? Perhaps there are other ways to do this.

Comment: FINRA:TICKER_SHORT_VOLUME supplies non-split-adjusted short volumes when calculating the short ratio, since volume is split-adjusted. You could correct if you multiply by the cummulative splitratio, but these obviously lie in the past, left of the split. However, you could also divide the current volume to the right of the split with the splitratio to obtain the non-adjusted short volumes.

Comment: So, judging by your code and comment, you want to apply to the value on each bar all the splits that occurred before it, that is, to the left of that bar, right?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was. At any moment in time, the provided data by FINRA is the short volume at that moment in time. Later splits should theoretically reduce that volume by the splitratio to be proportional to the outstanding shares (just like the normal volume is handled) i.e. I want to apply to the short_volume of each bar all the splits which occured AFTER, that is, right to that bar.

Comment: My idea is that I start with the array split_f=1 (full of ones). For each index that is smaller than the current selected split index, I multiply the entries of split_f by the splitratio. I toss out this split (in the while) and proceed with the next split (starting with the oldest split).

Comment: >> want to apply to the short_volume of each bar all the splits which occured AFTER, that is, right to that bar.
This isn't possible (by properly way) due to pine execution model. When you calc short_volume at ten's bar you cannot know what splits may occurred at 11's, 12's, ..., etc bars
Check out pine user manual on execution model section for deeper understanding https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html